# How to parse HTML from JavaScript in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, dom

What is the best way to parse (get a DOM tree of) a HTML result of XmlHttpRequest in Firefox?

EDIT:

I do *not* have the DOM tree, I want to acquire it.

XmlHttpRequest's "responseXML" works only when the result is actual XML, so I have only responseText to work with.

<s>The innerHTML hack doesn't seem to work with a complete HTML document (in <html></html>).</s> - turns out it works fine.

Comment: Browsers parsing plain html code since they are exist. But that's so sad that there is no simple, standard way that can invoke the browser's parser to make a HTMLDocument object from a html string...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**`innerHTML`** should work just fine, e.g.

```
// This would be after the Ajax request:
var myHTML = XHR.responseText;
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.innerHTML = myHTML.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g, '');

// tempDiv now has a DOM structure:
tempDiv.childNodes;
tempDiv.getElementsByTagName('a'); // etc. etc.
```

Comment: Looks like it's the best I can do. Thanks for the tip about <script>s.

Comment: If you're worried about <script>s being executed, then you'd also need to worry about other tricks such as SCRIPT being uppercase, or a null byte appearing part way through the word <script> etc.  But do you really need to be worried about <script>s being executed?

Comment: According to this page: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/513633-innerhtml-script-tag - you don't need to worry about script blocks being executed when added via innerHTML: "Script blocks inserted via innerHTML don't get executed in any browser
other than NS6" - though that was written in 2006.

Comment: What if the to be parsed document myHTML was a complete HTML document starting with <!DOCTYPE html><html>...? It wouldn't make much sense to have it as the innerHTML of a div, would it? Even if current browsers are able to ignore some of the markup to get a suitable replacement for the div's innerHTML, it doesn't sound as a clean solution to me.

Comment: This fails for "<tr><td>test</td></tr>" , it only does it correctly for Div

Answer (score 3):

At least for newer Firefox versions, an easier way is or will soon be available.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest indicates that starting from FF11 it will be possible to ask for a DOM directly from the XHR by setting the `responseType` attribute to `"document"`.  At that point, the HTML will be parsed and the DOM stuck into `responseXML` as for an XML document.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DOMParser to parse HTML - even tag soup:

```
var parser = new DOMParser()
parser.parseFromString('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>hi</title></head><body><p>hello<b>world</b></p>', 'text/html')
```

I don't know if it handles partial table markup well, but it should create the same DOM the browser itself does for pretty much any markup.

Answer (score 1):

Loop up the responseXML property of the XMLHttpRequest object. Furthermore, if you use innerHTML to append the responseText of an HTML-formatted response, the browser will parse the text and assemble it within the DOM all before even appending it into the document flow.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is XHTML, so it's valid XML, then DOMParser (Mozilla) or loadXML (IE) may help. If not, I can't think of anything better than stripping the  and  and then passing it to a 's innerHtml.

See 21.1.3 in Flanagan's Javascript guide (5th edition).

Colin