# Create a DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I created a input element with jQuery like that:

```
var element = $('<input />', {
  name: name1,
  id: id1,
  type: 'text'
});
```

And I want to return the DOM element associated with it. However, element is not a DOM (yet). How can I transform it to DOM element?

Comment: You have not attached it to the DOM tree but the underlying DOM element exists already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use  `element[0]` or `element.get(0)`.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery returns an array-like object of DOM elements. Using the array indexer will always allow you to get a specific element, like so:

```
var domElement = element[0];
```

Alternatively, jQuery provides a function just for that, [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
var domElement = element.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check this solutions to use maybe a DOM parser.
[Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)

or just use some native javascript functions.
[Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)