# How do I run javascript examples from sites like stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript

What needs to be added inorder to run an example like what is found on here: [Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements) in a basic HTML document?

Specifically I'm referring to the code:

```
var xmlString = "<div id='foo'><a href='#'>Link</a><span></span></div>"
  , parser = new DOMParser()
  , doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
doc.firstChild // => <div id="foo">...
doc.firstChild.firstChild // => <a href="#">...
```

I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlString = "<div id='foo'><a href='#'>Link</a><span></span></div>"
  , parser = new DOMParser()
  , doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
doc.firstChild;
doc.firstChild.firstChild;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As a beginner to javascript, a complete html copy and paste solution would be good to see how precisely it fits in.

Comment: You have posted an incomplete example (it was posted as example code that is missing actions).

Comment: Do you really want a general answer to your title question (likely to be closed) or only an explanation of that specific example code?

Comment: As a beginner to javascript I often see javascript examples posted like above, it seems they are always missing something that I need to add in to make it run. I'm sure it is very simple, but I just can't work it out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure if this is what you want, but if you want to run jQuery (or javascript) online, you can use http://jsfiddle.net/, but make sure when you're running a script, you have all the referenced variables and elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `// =>` comments are just trying to describe the value you'd get from the properties -- in each case, a DOM Object representing part of the markup.

It's up to you what you want to do with those values. For guidance, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM

But, you could simply output them with `console.log`:

```
console.log(doc.firstChild);
console.log(doc.firstChild.firstChild);
```

Or displaying their details in an element on the page:

```
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = doc.firstChild.nodeName;
```

Or, any of a plethora of other tasks.

---

For context:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo"></div>

        <script>
            var xmlString = "<div id='foo'><a href='#'>Link</a><span></span></div>"
              , parser = new DOMParser()
              , doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

            console.log(doc.firstChild);
            console.log(doc.firstChild.firstChild);

            document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = doc.firstChild.nodeName;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see a complete html dump for this with the code above so I can see how it fits in?

Comment: @peteskiii Sure. Edited my answer to include it.

Comment: I get 'undefined' when I see this on the screen.

Comment: @peteskiii Sorry. That was a poor example. `innerHTML` isn't available when parsing as `"text/xml"`. I've updated the examples to demonstrate with `nodeName`, instead.

Comment: when I run this I only see 'div' on the screen. Sorry!

Comment: @peteskiii That's the expected output, as that's the `nodeName` of `doc.firstChild`. It's perhaps not as useful of an example as `innerHTML`, but XML nodes don't appear to expose their markup.