# A regex to remove id, style, class attributes from HTML tags in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I got a html String in javascript and using regex I want to remove id, style and class attributes in html tags, for example I have:

```
New York City.<div style="padding:20px" id="upp" class="upper"><div style="background:#F2F2F2; color:black; font-size:90%; padding:10px 10px; width:500px;">This message is.</div></div>
```

I want this String to become:

```
New York City.<div><div>This message is.</div></div>
```

Comment: /me is casting a link to the legendary don't-parse-html-with-regex answer...

Comment: How about `removeAttribute()`, maybe?

Comment: [Convert it to a DOM element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements) and use the appropriate tools to manipulate it. That's a far more stable solution.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of parsing the HTML using regular expressions, which is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), you could take advantage of the DOM functionality that is available in all browsers. We need to be able to walk the DOM tree first:

```
var walk_the_DOM = function walk(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walk(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};
```

Now parse the string and manipulate the DOM:

```
var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML= '<!-- your HTML here -->';
walk_the_DOM(wrapper.firstChild, function(element) {
    if(element.removeAttribute) {
        element.removeAttribute('id');
        element.removeAttribute('style');
        element.removeAttribute('class');
    }
});
result = wrapper.innerHTML;
```

See also [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTDX6/).

Comment: Example is different from jsfiddle, `walk_the_DOM(wrapper.firstChild` should be `walk_the_DOM(wrapper` otherwise only first element gets striped from atributes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to remove everything but the div tag names-

```
string=string.replace(/<(div)[^>]+>/ig,'<$1>');
```

This will return `<DIV>` if the html is upper Case.

Comment: This doesn't work for attributes that contain a `>` character:
`<div data-attr="> this is a value">Text</div>'.replace(/<(div)[^>]+>/ig,'<$1>')`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the attributes, then regex is the wrong tool. I'd suggest, instead:

```
function stripAttributes(elem){
    if (!elem) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var attrs = elem.attributes;
        while (attrs.length) {
            elem.removeAttribute(attrs[0].name);
        }
    }
}

var div = document.getElementById('test');

stripAttributes(div);
```

​[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3fnzn/).

Answer (score 1):

i used this

```
var html = 'New York City.<div style="padding:20px" id="upp"
class="upper"><div style="background:#F2F2F2; color:black; font-size:90%; padding:10px 10px; width:500px;">This message is.</div></div>';

function clear_attr(str,attrs){
    var reg2 = /\s*(\w+)=\"[^\"]+\"/gm;
    var reg = /<\s*(\w+).*?>/gm;
    str = str.replace(reg,function(match, i) {
        var r_ = match.replace(reg2,function(match_, i) {
            var reg2_ = /\s*(\w+)=\"[^\"]+\"/gm;
            var m = reg2_.exec(match_);
            if(m!=null){
                if(attrs.indexOf(m[1])>=0){
                    return match_;
                }
            }
            return '';
        });        
        return r_;
    });
    return str;
}
clear_attr(html,[]);
```

Comment: hi code works good, but still only these attributes are not removed, `<p data-spm-anchor->` and some other data attributes

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression. That is fast (in production time) and easy (in development time).

```
htmlCode = htmlCode.replace(/<([^ >]+)[^>]*>/ig,'<$1>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to parse HTML with regexes will cause problems. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/28324) may be helpful in explaining them. If you are using jQuery, you may be able to do something like this:

```
var transformedHtml = $(html).find("*").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style").removeAttr("class").outerHTML()
```

For this to work, you need to be using the [outerHTML plugin described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419877/28324).

If you don't want to use jQuery, it will be trickier. These question may have some helpful answers as to how to convert the string to a collection of DOM elements: [Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements), [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro). You may be able to loop through the elements and remove the attributes using the built-in [removeAttr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeAttribute) function. I don't have the time or motivation to figure out all the details for you.

Comment: Even though this answer is correct by itself, but still doesn't give even a hint about what OP should do instead

Comment: Good point. Sorry but I had to link to that post. I may expand my answer to come up with suggestions for what to do.

Comment: Thanks but for some reasons I don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

A plain script solution would be something like:

```
function removeProperties(markup) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = markup;
  var el, els = div.getElementsByTagName('*');

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    el = els[i];
    el.id = '';
    el.style = '';
    el.className = '';
  }
  // now add elements to the DOM
  while (div.firstChild) {
   // someElement.appendChild(div.firstChild);
  }
}
```

A more general solution would get the property names as extra arguments, or say a space separated string, then iterate over the names to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about RegEx, but I sure as hell know about jQuery.

Convert the given HTML string into a DOM element, parse it, and return its contents.

```
function cleanStyles(html){
    var temp = $(document.createElement('div'));
        temp.html(html);

        temp.find('*').removeAttr('style');
        return temp.html();
}
```