# JQuery string clean html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

For a script I am making I am having the user insert text into a textarea, this text is expected to contain "dirty" html.
I want to take the user input and "clean" the html it contains.
So let's say a user inserts the following string:
`<h2 class='example' style='position:absolute;width:50px;'>Example</h2>`
I want it to output as follows:
`<h2>Example</h2>`

I have managed to make a script that detects the use of the `<h2>` tag and can remove it, but as said above, I don't want to fully remove it, only "clean" it.
The code I have so far:

*edit: [made a JSFiddle for easier(?) use](https://jsfiddle.net/m6mv15z5/)*

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
form{
    width: 98.5%;
    height: 90%;
}
div{
    position: absolute;
}
#leftContent, #rightContent{
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
}
#bottomContent{
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 99%;
    height: 10%;
}
textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#rightContent{
    right: 10px;
}
input[type="submit"]{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 76px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div id="leftContent"><textarea id="textarea" class="left" name="insertText">Insert text</textarea></div>
        <div id="rightContent"><textarea readonly id="textarea" class="right" name="resultText">Result</textarea></div>
        <div id="bottomContent"><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Process Text"/></div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Short code
        function matchRuleShort(str, rule) {
          return new RegExp("^" + rule.split("*").join(".*") + "$").test(str);
        }
        //Form send
        $("form").submit(function(e){
            var insert = $(".left").val(); //left field
            if(insert == "Vul tekst in" || insert == ""){ //Check if inserted text
                $(".right").html("Please change the text!");
            }else{
                var result = $("<div>" + insert + "</div>");

                result.find('h2')
                    .replaceWith(function(){ return this.childNodes }); //This removes the entire <h2> tag

                var res = result.html();
                $(".right").html(res);
                //alert(matchRuleShort(insert, '<h2*')); //returns true: h2 tag found
                //$(".right").html(result);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I best go about achieving what I intend to do?
I have tried about everything I ran into on here, google and on the JQuery website itself, but nothing I can find seems to do what I need it to do.

Comment: Oh very nice find, the first answer there does seem to indeed fix my problem, thank you! @Bekim his answer worked if it didn't contain multiple of the thing I needed to strip, but this one works with both easily.

Answer (score 1):

Some guidelines to your Question.
1. Use ID to manipulate inputs text.
2. Use ID as unique , you have used the same id for two inputs.
3. At the end you can clean value by using the Val() or empty but you have to make the value get for the request first.

if it's not the solution. Pls. elaborate the Problem...

Comment: Oops, completely missed that I used that ID twice, removed them now - since they ended up not needed (for now at least)  Where do I use the val()? I have it to get the user input from the left field, but if I add it to the res or result it doesn't do anything anymore, in an attempt to elaborate a bit: I am trying to scan a text (user input) for html tags (h2, p, etc) and clean them to their base form (eg <h2 class='test'> becomes <h2>) while I can remove the entire tag, I cant clean it, the only constant I know is the opening of the tag (<h2, <p) anything after that is a "wildcard")

Answer (score 1):

The solution from the page making this question a duplicate is vulnerable to script injections with malicious intent. Check this out: (and wait about 5s)
...in a real world scenario - you will not get an alert box message!

```js
var str = '<img id="ides" class="classname" src="http:\/\/asdf.jpg" onerror="(function(){alert(\'just executed a nasty script!\')})()"\/>';

var walk_the_DOM = function walk(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walk(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};

var wrapper = document.createElement('div');

wrapper.innerHTML = str; 
  
walk_the_DOM(wrapper, function(el) {
    if(el.removeAttribute) {
        el.removeAttribute('id');
        el.removeAttribute('style');
        el.removeAttribute('class');
    }
});
result = wrapper.innerHTML;

//alert(result);
```

---

Here is an function I've written and [published](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c9afdc6-41c5-46f1-8bd4-21dfd907c09b/potentially-harmful-html?forum=iewebdevelopment) few years ago that does what you are asking for and a lot more...

```
function sterilize(HTMLString){ /* b.b. Troy III p.a.e. */
        HTMLString=HTMLString.replace( /<img /gi, "<imga ");
        var att, x=0, y, coll,c=[],
            probe = document.createElement("div");
            probe.innerHTML = HTMLString;
            coll = probe.getElementsByTagName("*");
        while(coll[x])coll[x]?c.push(coll[x++]):0;

        for( x in c )
        if( /(script|object|embed|iframe)/i.
        /*you can blacklist more tags here!*/
            test( c[x].tagName ) ){
            c[x].outerHTML="";
        } else {
        if( c[x].href)/java/.test(coll[x].protocol )?c[x].href="#":0;
            att = c[x].attributes;
        for( y in att ) if(att[y])
        if( /(^on|style)/i.test(att[y].name) )
            c[x].removeAttribute( att[y].name );
        }
        c=probe.innerHTML.replace( /imga/gi, "img" );
        return  c.replace( /<\/img>/gi, "" );
    }
```

p.s.: You don't have to remove class or id attributes they are perfectly safe. but since you need perfectly clean tags and tags only - you can use following upgrade. Get it from the attached snippet.

---

```js
function sterilize(HTMLString){ /* b.b. Troy III p.a.e. */
        HTMLString=HTMLString.replace( /<img /gi, "<imga ");
        var att, x=0, y, coll,c=[],
            probe = document.createElement("div");
            probe.innerHTML = HTMLString;
            coll = probe.getElementsByTagName("*");
        while(coll[x])coll[x]?c.push(coll[x++]):0;

        for( x in c )
        if( /(script|object|embed|iframe)/i.
        /*you can blacklist more tags here!*/
            test( c[x].tagName ) ){
            c[x].outerHTML="";
        } else {
        if( c[x].href)/java/.test(coll[x].protocol )?c[x].href="#":0;
            att = c[x].attributes;
        while(att.length)att.removeNamedItem(att[0].name);
        }
        c=probe.innerHTML.replace( /imga/gi, "img" );
        return  c.replace( /<\/img>/gi, "" );
    };

console.log( sterilize( form.outerHTML ) );
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div id="leftContent">
    <textarea id="textarea" class="left" name="insertText">Insert text</textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="rightContent">
    <textarea readonly id="textarea" class="right" name="resultText">Result</textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomContent">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Process Text"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do what I need just fine, but I'd prefer it if classes are removed to due to potential css attached to the page it is displayed on, when I try to add an if for class or add an OR statement to the if for class removal it only removes the class and leaves the style, is there a way to do both or do you suggest taking the risk of the classes?

Comment: @DevelopmentSideShowMedia fast fix is to add the class and\or id attribute to the filter, as in:  `if( /(^on|style|class|id)/i.test(...`

Comment: I've tried adding the |class to that if statement, it will remove the class then but leaves the style tag, it wont remove both if an element has both a class and an inline style

Comment: even if I copy paste it it still wont remove them both from the same element. The solution in the post that got this marked as a duplicate has worked in removing both of them though.

Comment: @DevelopmentSideShowMedia Yes you are right - check the upgraded version I'm using it to clear the code of your form or the entire document for that matter, to demonstrate that any string html will do.

Comment: @DevelopmentSideShowMedia If you are referring to the top most solution from there - you should reconsider your safety. Safety comes first. To illustrate it  for your convenience try:  
`wrapper.innerHTML = "<img src='http://asdf.jpg' onerror='(function(){alert(\"just executed a nasty script\")})()'>"` you will see the alert message which confirms that you are not safe. Have fun. :)

Comment: the top one is indeed the one I was referring to, I've tried posting `<img src='http://asdf.jpg' onerror='(function(){alert(\"just executed a nasty script\")})()'>` in the textarea that gets processed and nothing happened, aside from a message in the console `asdf.jpg/:1 GET http://asdf.jpg/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
text_edit.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: @DevelopmentSideShowMedia - Well, I wasn't going to give the exact code that would really execute here in the open. But if you really like to see it in action I will.

Answer (score 0):

Do you parse the input to php?

```
<?php $clean = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>",'<$1$2>', $dirty); ?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that in just Javascript/JQuery? I'd prefer to not use php for this so that the user wont have to reload the page.

Comment: You could use ajax then, but then it would get much more complicated than simple js.

With js you can go with .removeAttr(element). Do a foreach with plain js or use jquery.
jQuery.fn.removeAttributes = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
      return item.name;
    });
    var img = $(this);
    $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
    img.removeAttr(item);
    });
  });
}
var res = result.removeAttributes().html();

Answer (score 0):

As it is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12360574/1561148 where a user asks how he can achieve this by using regular expressions, the idea is to walk through the DOM and use `removeAttribute()` to every element.

I don't know what is your use case but maybe searching also for `HTML sanitization` might help you. I found this: https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html