# Extrating <img> tags from HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page that has many elements (tables, divs e.t.c) I get them as string and I want to extract this format `<img src="(whatever char).jpg" (whatever char)>` from the string, I tried regexp tutorials but couldn't do anything as it was to complicated to me. And I need only the first occurrence, thanks.

Comment: You don't want to use regexp for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think regex is the right way to go about this:

```
var all_images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var filtered_images = [];

for (var i = 0; i < all_images.length; i++) {
    var image = all_images[i];

    if (image.hasAttribute('src')) {
        filtered_images.push(image);
    }
}
```

If you were using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), the code would be much simpler:

```
var images = $('img[src]');
```

Comment: there are 2 img elements and I want the one with the src attribute

Answer (score 2):

<del>Is this your need?</del>

<del>`"<img src=\"aaa.jpg\" (whatever char)>".match(/src="([^"]*)"/)[1]`</del>

Agree with Blender, use dom instead, regexp is not a good solution.

Comment: This approach will not be good.  The problem is that it is nearly impossible to write a robust regex to find the image tags.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory link to the answer why you should think twice about using regular expressions to parse HTML:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

That being said, I wonder why you have a websites HTML code as a string and not as a DOM tree and need to manipulate it in javascript. That looks like a quite uncommon use-case. When your script runs on the website you want to parse, you can use document.getElementsByTagName("img") to get an array of all image DOM nodes on the website. But when you really have the sourcecode of ANOTHER website as a string and want to parse it, try this regular expression.

```
<img.*?src="(.*?)"
```

Comment: You can convert a string into a DOM object pretty easily (on most browsers): http://stackoverflow.com/a/3104237/464744