# Function to exclude specific tags from xml string

Tags: c#

I have given XML string with a list of html tag like "`<p>, <a>, <img>, <link>`" etc.

Now I want to make generic function where I will be passing the list of html tags or can be one tag as well which I want to exclude from the passed XML string. Function will return the whole string back without excluded tags.

```
  public const String[] htmlTags = new String[] { "<p>", "a", "img" };
  string result = strString.ExcludeHTMLTags(htmlTags); //I will write the String extension not an issue, please suggest how to exclude tags from exisiting string.
```

EDIT:

I am trying below code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Remove HTML tags from string using char array.
/// </summary>
public static string StripTagsCharArray(string source, String[] htmlTags)
{
    char[] array = new char[source.Length];
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    bool inside = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        foreach (String htmlTag in htmlTags)
        {
            char let = source[i];
            String tag = "<" + "htmlTag"; //How to handle this as this is character
            if (let == tag)
            {
                inside = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (let == '>')
            {
                inside = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (!inside)
            {
                array[arrayIndex] = let;
                arrayIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
    return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
}
```

EDIT 2: Using Regex

```
String[] htmlTags = new String[] { "a", "img", "p" };
private const string STR_RemoveHtmlTagRegex = "</?{0}[^<]*?>";
public static string RemoveHtmlTag(String input, String[] htmlTags)
{
    String strResult = String.Empty;
    foreach (String htmlTag in htmlTags)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex(String.Format(STR_RemoveHtmlTagRegex, htmlTag.Trim()), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        strResult = reg.Replace(input, String.Empty);
        input = strResult;
    }
    return strResult;
}
```

Now the problem is that it is not removing value of tag, so if there is "Testing

" then it returns "Testing", I want to remove whole tag with values as well.

Comment: Added few more code attempt, however having some doubts in it

Answer (score 1):

Convert html to DOM-tree and remove element-nodes with name containing in given excluding tag list

Comment: do we have any function which is does above things any examples

Comment: You can use DOMParser. Here is the example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements

Comment: What about passing list of htmls tags which I want to exclude from xml string.

Comment: Show your code where you have a problem, then would be able to help ;)

Comment: Added my sample code here I am tring to read each character however I am need to check whole tag and remove it

Comment: You've ignored suggestion. sad. Please follow two given anwsers - use DOM utilities

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT, built as a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files, and you can fix a string the way you want, modify the DOM, add nodes, copy nodes, well.