# Converting an HTML string to a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html

Say one has,

```
var some_html = '<div class = "am_hold">' +
    '<img name="bo_im" id="' + val.id + '" class="bookmark_image" src="' + val.favicon + '">' +
    '<a target="_blank" name="bookmark_link" class="bookmark_link" href = "' +
    val.url + '" id="' + val.id + '">' + val.title + '</a>' +
    '<div><div class = "bookmark_menu"></div></div>' +
    '</div>';
```

is it possible to do

```
var some_element = `some_function`(some_html);
```

Is there an implementation for some_function (1) with out using a library and (2) with using a library.

Comment: `var d = document.createElement('div'); d.innerHTML = some_html;` ?

Comment: Try this info `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Create a temporary container for your HTML, then gets its content. Something like:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = some_html;
return d.firstChild;
```

Comment: @pure_code.com: fewer lines of code is not always the best method. Just because there may be a one-liner solution, doesn't mean it's the _best_ implementation.

Comment: @pure_code.com: But there isn't. You can put those three lines into a function if you want to (*edit:* You actually have to since the last line is a `return` statement). If you don't know how to define functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html.

Comment: Then simply stick this in the body of a function called "some_function" and call that.

Comment: @pure_code.com Here's a one-liner: `var d = document.createElement('div'); d.innerHTML = some_html; return d.firstChild;`

Comment: @pure_code.com Then wrap it in a function ...

Comment: could this cause a memory leak because firstchild is still referenced by d?  like say you were doing something like otherElement.appendChild(d.firstchild);

Answer (score 5):

Try the below code

```
    var myname = 'John Doe';

//This is using Jquery
var htmltext = '<p style="color:red">'+myname+'This is a test</p>'
$('#one').html(htmltext);


//This is pure javascript
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML='<p style="color:red">'+myname+'This is a test</p>';
```

**[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/ZQH5f/)**

I am building a string and appending it to an html element using html() rather than text() function . This will be treated as a HTML tag by browser and diplay the changes in the UI as seen in the fiddle.

Comment: Don't forget to add an explanation to your code for those who might not be familiar with `jQuery` or `JavaScript`.

Comment: That JQUERY code is perfect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

jQuery.parseHTML()-function might help you.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Comment: [`jQuery.parseHTML`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L455-L480) is just a more elaborate version of [Kolink's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16816777/298053).

Comment: Hope this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3104237/2335272

Comment: @DonnyDee that answer will only work for HTML which is XML-valid (i.e. not all HTML).