# How to find the id of user specified html tags in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find the id of user specified html tags. For instance the user could input:

`<p id="HiImATag"></p>`
or they could input any other tag with any other id. I need a way to find the id of specific html tags (such as getting the id from `<li>` or `<p>` tags without knowing the id in the first place) in pure javascript; however, if it is not possible I could use JQuery. Thank you in advance!

Comment: where the user input : <p id="HiImATag"></p> ?

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: Can you show what you've attempt achieving and the challenge you are facing?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob I have tried using a regex but it is extremely buggy and doesn't find only the id.

Comment: @nyedidikeke same as the above message.

Comment: Your JavaScript code, trying to resolve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("p"), function(el) {
  alert(el.id);
});
```

```html
<p id="hello"></p>
<p id="world"></p>
<p id="foo"></p>
```

Comment: This just saved my day! Thank you so much!

Comment: @bismuthboss Sure, don't forget to upvote or accept answers that solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].id;
```

'0' is the index of the occurence.

https://jsfiddle.net/bhv627pe/

Comment: I tried this: `alert(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].id);` and it alerts and empty result when i had several p tags with ids

Comment: It works fine on jsfiddle. Please check is you used the right index.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript, you can create a temporary DOM element, add the string as its `innerHTML`, grab the first child (which would be the element created from the string), and get its `id`. Borrowed from [Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16816777).

```
var userElement = '<p id="HiImATag"></p>';
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = userElement;
var element = d.firstChild;
var id = element.id;
```

You mentioned that you can use jQuery. Another way to do this would be to create a jQuery object using the string and get the id attribute from the object.

```
var userElement = '<p id="HiImATag"></p>';
var id = $(userElement).attr('id');
console.log(id); // prints out HiImATag
```

Comment: @bismuthboss note that this answer is based on the assumption that the user is inputting a string into a textbox or something, since you mentioned trying to use a regex in a comment above.