# How can a span element be appended to an array of Strings, .join(","), and rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have

```
var pos = ["a","b"]
pos.unshift(<span className="common">Common Word</span>)
var parts_of_speech = pos.join(', ')
```

Rendering `{pos}` prints `Common Word` properly and I can style the css class. Printing `{parts_of_speech}` results in `[object Object]` instead of `Common Word` being printed.

What can be done to make this do what I would expect or is this the wrong way to go about doing this?

Comment: This might help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816726/converting-an-html-string-to-a-dom-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816726/converting-an-html-string-to-a-dom-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `<span className="common">Common Word</span>` in JSX, you are not dealing with a span element. It is actually just a JavaScript function call:

```
React.createElement(
  "span",
  { className: "common" },
  "Common Word"
);
```

You can [use Babel to get the result above](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=DwZwDghgdgBAxgGwiEA5CBbApgXgERwD2GGhUeAfAMLGmwDqhATgCbAD040FQA).

So you are getting the result of joining the result of a function with a string.

Your code translate to the following with Babel:

```
var pos = ["a", "b"];
pos.unshift(React.createElement(
  "span",
  { className: "common" },
  "Common Word"
));
var parts_of_speech = pos.join(', ');
```

So if React.createElement returns some object, it should have a `toString()` method that outputs `[object Object]`.

[Like this example](https://jsfiddle.net/8Loj6f1t/):

```
"use strict";

var pos = ["a", "b"];
pos.unshift((function() { return {}; })());
var parts_of_speech = pos.join(', ');

console.log(parts_of_speech)
```

Comment: I want the end result to have a span element with a css class that I can style (while joining it with other normal strings). Is there a simple way to do that or would I have to render that span element separately from the array of Strings?

Comment: You should make an array of React components (which are just the result of function calls!): `var pos = [<span>a</span>, <span>b</span>];` and then in the render() function's return value you need only say {pos} and React will know how to render an array of JSX "elements".

Comment: You can also map an array of strings to an array of span components like so: `['a', 'b'].map(label => (<span>{label}</span>))`

Comment: Making the array an array of JSX elements sounds like it would work. Just a thought but I wonder if that is the most ideal solution though because it seems to me, this solution would pollute the html with possibly unneeded spans.

Comment: Then what prevents you from just doing `a,<span className="...">Common Word</span>,b` inside the return value of the render function?

Comment: I guess you have missed " here `pos.unshift("<span className='common'>Common Word</span>")`

Comment: If the array is empty and I need Common Word then I don't need a comma, if the array is not empty then I need the comma. If Common Word is not needed then simply joining the array with .join(', ') is fine. The best of both worlds is if I can add Common Word to the array then just join everything together. So far it looks like the only way that will happen is if I add a span to every string in the array?

Comment: @Umesh I tried that but that surprisingly prints out literally that string. the span className.... same with class instead of className.