# get element from string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, types

I send a request with AJAX to retrieve Html from a page like this :

```
 function getHTML() {
        //set ajax call
        var options = {
            url: '/Controller',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }
        //make call
        return $.ajax(options).then(querySucceded).fail(queryFailed);

        //handle theajax callback
        function querySucceded(data) {
            console.log(data);
            //THE NEXT LINE IS THE PROBLEME
            var val = data.getElementByName("somename").val();
        }

        function queryFailed(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //var msg = 'Error getting data. ' + textStatus;
            console.log('Error while getting data');
        }
    }
```

so the ajax call works great and the `querySucceded` function is called, and the data is retrieved correctly.

but the data is considered as a string.
how can I manipulate the DOM inside the data object using jquery, like:

```
$("somename").val();
```

Comment: what is the result of console.log(data); ?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements

Comment: @Sankalp Mishra lol the console.log(data) returns this : <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="nkCjpcx7jnGRIS8ixgY74Nb3Ave06WXQ8moQty73cE_AcKkO6YHjjAFvfCpDK-YPP0cZfXosZ‌​4Q3lM_RVynzkTWFgdhWnm1tgCsEHtXocKY1" />

Comment: and i want to get the value of the input tag

Comment: i solved the probleme i use this :
   

    var xmlString = "<div id='foo'><a href='#'>Link</a><span></span></div>"
      , parser = new DOMParser()
      , doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
    doc.firstChild // => <div id="foo">...
    doc.firstChild.firstChild // => <a href="#">...

thanks u all for ur quick answers, it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

**getElementByName is available on the document object**

Also it is supposed to be `getElementsByName` . And not on the response HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use some jQuery magic to get a DOM structure from a long html string:

```
$("<div/>").html(data).contents();
```

I'm not sure, but I think that $(data) directly will return an array of nodes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $data = $(data),
var value = $data.filter("your selector here").val()

console.log(value)
```