# Remove specific tags and their content in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace, tags

How can I remove div tags and their content in javascript ?

I tried the following script, but that remove only the tags and leave the content.

```js
var res, html = document.getElementById('source').value;
res = html.replace(/(<div[^>]+>|<div>|<\/div>)/g, "");
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res;
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="source">
  <p>
      <input type="text"/>
      <div class="parent"><div>inner01</div><div>inner02</div></div>
      <span></span>
  </p>
</textarea>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

Comment: You can't do that with regex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `div` is an actual string, try this regex instead:

```
<div.*<\/div>
```

- A dot is any one single character: `.`
- followed by an asterisk witch is zero or more instances of whatever precedes it: `*` *****
- and in order to interpret the forward slash literally escape it with a backward slash: `\`

***** *a plus: `+` would suffice as well -- one or more instances of whatever precedes it.*

```js
var res, html = document.getElementById('source').value;
res = html.replace(/<div.*<\/div>/g, "");
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res;
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="source">
  <p>
      <input type="text"/>
      <div class="parent"><div>inner01</div><div>inner02</div></div>
      <span></span>
      <div class="parent"><input></div>
  </p>
</textarea>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

***Note:*** An extra `div` is added to demonstrate that multiple instances are removed properly and without removing "tags" occurring between `div` "tags".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** epascarello has pointed out that I'm an idiot, so this should be acceptable at least in this example:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="source">
  <p>
    <input type="text">
    <div id="parent"><div>inner01</div><div>inner02</div></div>
    <span></span>
  </p>
</textarea>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
<button onclick="removeDiv()">
Click me to remove div!
</button>
```

JS:

```
function removeDiv() {
  var string = document.getElementById("source").value;
  var s1 = string.split("<div")[0];
  var s2 = string.split("</div>");
  string = s1 + s2[s2.length-1];
  document.getElementById("result").value = string;
}
```

**The problem:** This removes *everything* between the first opening div tag and the last closing div tag, so if there's something you want to leave in between, it'll be deleted. Example:

```
<p>
  <div>Some stuff</div>
  <span>Stuff to keep</span>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
</p>
```

Will end up as:

```
<p>
</p>
```

So it will not work in every case.

Comment: But i is a string, not DOM

Comment: @epascarello Is it? I was under the impression that the asker wanted to remove a div tag from a DOM by getting the textarea's innerHTML, passing it as a string, and then performing a regex operation on it and passing it back to the DOM. This solution removes the regex entirely, manipulating the DOM directly.

Comment: How i can do that with string HTML

Comment: @MaclainAnderson Yes, Look at the HTML!

Comment: @epascarello Apologies for my idiocy, I did not think it through. I'm working on a different solution. You could extract the textarea's html, place it in a div, do some DOM manipulation there, then move it to the second textarea. Seems very roundabout, though.

Comment: I found this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940274/remove-div-and-its-content-from-html-string

Comment: @MustaphaFersaoui That solution will work, but it requires JQuery. For those who don't wish to use JQuery for whatever reason, you can accomplish the same thing by following my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

here is **example** for **clearing** or **removing** div contents on html page you can select which one is suitable & you may  as well count them , i have made this example for you where you can click on each div content and as per click it will remove content . also there is a **button** if you click it , it will **count** all **divs** on page clear it's content then completely **remove** its content along with **sub** **tags** child's inside it.

its important to keep this sequence of scripts other ways it will give error and scripts must be under the div tags so it can read the divs .

i have used sweetalert js library for styling the message alerts modals as well i have used j query library within the page please check snip code .

**note : Your Source Example is included in my code and**  by **clicking** on div it will **clear** content & by **clicking** on **button** it will **clear** and **remove** , i **left only one to avoid deleting** so you can tweak it and understand how it works .

Edited : Frankly , after testing this on snip , i have noticed the counters giving totals of hidden div tags as well so am assuming these totals is counting also the snip tool window even the hidden one .

good luck

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<!-- must use in order to make XP Themes render -->
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" content="Yes" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<div id="unknown_id_Number">

<textrea id="unknown_idtxtbox">
<p>
  <input type="text"/>
  <div class="parent"><div>inner01</div><div>inner02</div></div>
  <span></span>
</p>
</textarea>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="div6">

<textrea>
<p>
  <input type="text"/>
  <div class="parent"><div>inner01</div><div>inner02</div></div>
  <span></span>
</p>
</textarea>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
</div>



<div id = "div1" value="i am div content" style= "width:200px;height:70px;background:orange;text-align:center;padding:5%;color:white;">
i am content of div1

</div>

<div id = "#div2" value="txt2"  style= "width:200px;height:70px;background:pink;text-align:center;">
i am content of div2

</div>

<div id = 'div3' value="txt3"  style= "width:200px;height:70px;background:green;text-align:center;">
i am content of div3

</div>




<button onclick="removealldiv()">Click to remove all div contents</button>

<script>
function removealldiv(){

// insert total divs on divs variable
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");


for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
   //do something to each div like

   divs[i].innerHTML = " ";
   divs[i].remove();
if ( i = i ) {
swal("i have clear then removed about "+ i +" div's on this page ",'success');
}
}


}
</script>

<script>




$("div").click( function(){


    var name = $(this).attr("id");
  

swal({
  title: "Are you sure you want to delete the content of div id = " +name+"?",
  text: "if you click delete , the content of your div will be removed",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
    swal("Poof! your div content is cleared now ", {

      icon: "success",
    });
if  ( name = name )  {
         $(this).text(' ');
    }
  }


 else {
    swal("your div content is safe , the content will remain on page ");
  }
});

});

</script>




</body>


</html>
```