# Using DOM Methods on User Selected HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, file, dom

Is there a way to use DOM methods such as `getElementById("id")` or `getElementsByTagName("tag")` on a file that is selected by the user?

My program has the user select a set of HTML files that are formatted in a specific way that is somewhat difficult to search through when treated like one big string, but would be very easy if I could use DOM methods.

I am currently using the HTML5 File API to get a `FileList` and a `FileReader` object to parse the files and create strings.

Is using DOM methods possible, or alternatively, is there a better way to parse selected HTML files? A library like JSoup would be helpful, is there something similar in JavaScript?

Comment: So you want to parse HTML on the server? What server side language are you using? or do you want to parse html read on the client side? (i.e. not uploaded)

Comment: @AlexK. `is there something similar in JavaScript?`

Comment: By "uploaded" do you mean "Selected in a file element", because that is what it sounds like you are describing, and it is happening on the client before any uploading takes place.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it is being selected in a File element, not uploaded. My mistake.

Comment: As in; [Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)

Comment: It would be great if you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser but it doesn't seem to have good support for HTML

Comment: That's the way to do it then as far as I can see, what the objection?

Comment: Could someone provide me an example of how converting the HTML document into a mass of DOM elements could help me to use methods like getElementById("id")? Some example code would be a great help.

Comment: No idea if this would work, but could you use JavaScript to create an iFrame, then inject the html into the iFrame using .innerHTML and use the DOM functions to manipulate?

Comment: @Ian Although it doesn't provide universal support, the DOMParser does exactly what I need it to. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment but if you submit it as an answer I will certainly accept it as correct.

Comment: @BrianB. Sure thing, just added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MDN, there isn't good compatibility for `DOMParser` using `text/html` as the type, it seems to still parse fine with `application/xml` when providing HTML. Here's an example:

```
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    str = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><div id='div1'>asdf</div></body></html>",
    doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "application/xml");

console.log(doc.getElementById("div1").textContent);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8AzBp/1/

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full text of the file, you could always load it into a div, which would then cause the browser to generate DOM for said file. You could then use the methods you described.