# Find DOM element in text content using javascript

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, getelementbyid

Please push me towards a duplicate of this question if possible.  I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find it.

How do I do a getElementById on text content?

```
var test = '<div id="thisDiv">HI</div>';
```

How do I select thisDiv if it's not a part of the DOM?

Comment: But.... how can you getElement, if it's not an element...?

Comment: You have a string there, not a DOM element.

Comment: What's the easiest way to get the value then of thisDiv if it's a string?

Comment: use RegEx (e.g. `/<(.|\n)*?>/g`)

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3104237/2563028

Comment: are you willing to use jquery?

Comment: Trying to avoid using jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an element, set your string as its `innerHTML` and then search inside that ...

Something like

```
var test = '<div id="thisDiv">HI</div>';
var element = document.createElement('DIV');
element.innerHTML = test;

alert(element.textContent);
```

(*changed the initial `outerHTML` as you can only maintain a reference to the originaly created element, and not the new one that is created by the new html*)

Answer (score 0):

For getting the text value inside your tags, use RegEx:

```
var re = new RegExp("<(.|\n)*?>", "g");
var content = test.replace(re,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary DIV and populate it with your string. Even then, your ability to access it would be limited. Add it to the DOM to access it using getElementById.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<div id="thisDiv">HI</div>';
alert(div.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating that extra element, we could just add it to the body...

```
var test = '<div id="thisDiv">HI</div>';
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = test;
console.log(document.getElementById('thisDiv'));
```

**[Obligatory Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6MDg/)**

Getting just the text...

```
console.log(document.getElementById('thisDiv').textContent); // returns HI
```