# How can I get the body contents out of a variable containing HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable `htmlSource` containing HTML code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title> 


</head> 
<body>xxx some code here yy</body> 
</html>
```

How can I create a new variable `htmlBodyOnly` that contains only "xxx some code here yy". If possible I would like to do this with a regular expression. I am just not sure how to exclude the start and end using a regex or something similar.

Sorry but I don't have jQuery to use to help. I am working just on a javascript variable. Not working on the DOM.

Comment: do you mean that you want to get the content between the `<body>`-tags ?

Comment: You're sure you want to use a regular expression instead of an HTML parser? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: What is known about the string? Are any parts of it reliably consistent? Can there be invalid HTML?

Comment: @tvanfosson: OP doesn't want to parse the entire document.

Comment: A cheap solution is to do `var x = document.createElement("div"); x.innerHTML = str; console.log(x);` and remove the tags left. Better solution is [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Comment: ...well anyway, if your `<body>` is always a plain tag like that, then don't bother with a regex, Just do a `var str = html.split("<body>")[1]` and then slice away the trailing tags. Or use a simple regex that just targets the `body` and potential attributes. I don't think there's any need to parse the whole document if the string is fairly reliable.

Comment: @Samantha_J There are no variables in the code provided. Please explain what you want.

Comment: The string is an ASP.NET response web page of HTML. I just need to get the body out of it. Hope it's valid HTML as it's 100% created by Microsoft.

Comment: @cookiemonster - Your suggestions looks good but how could I do that as I have a <body> and a </body>.

Comment: @SamanthaJ that's funny

Comment: Can't it/you just send the relevant data? I don't use ASP.NET, but it would seem a shame to send an entire document if you only need a piece of it.

Comment: ...on the resulting string, you could do `.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf("</body>"))`, though again, this assumes consistent markup is being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ugly, but you can keep it as a string with this method:

```
htmlsource.substring(htmlsource.indexOf("<body>")+6, htmlsource.indexOf("</body>"))
```

The `+6` is because the string `"<body>"` has 6 characters and the indexOf method returns the index of the first character in the string to search for.

Here's proof that it works given your example: http://jsfiddle.net/9wBkf/

This assumes that the body tag will have no attributes i.e. `<body class="myClass>`

Comment: What if the body has some attributes? The best way to parse something is to build an abstract syntax tree; `DOMParser` does this for you.

Comment: If the markup format is reliable, I think this is the way to go, though I'd probably use `.lastIndexOf()` for the `</body>`. Better to avoid a full parse if it isn't needed.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Good point... if that's the case then regex would be the best solution, though I am not familiar enough with regex to offer help in that case...

Comment: We could play "what if" games all day *(which could be used against DOM parsing too)*. A regex for the open tag could be `/<body[^>]*>/i`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DOMParser` to parse the html and extract the content of the body. See this SO question: [Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)

```
var parser = new DOMParser()
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringToParse, "text/html")
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML)
```

[Here is a Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/yA3pA/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which regular expression you can use for that, but I think I know an alternative solution. You can also 'convert' your var to a DOM-object and then read the body-child.

[Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)