# vanilla js - get ID of element inside another element, which isn't part of the document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlString 
var obj = {};
obj.doctors = div.getElementById('doctors');
```

Is there a sensible way to find an ID within an element which is not yet attached to the DOM? Don't want to use JQuery here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)

Comment: that's not what I'm asking at all

Comment: The only way you can query by ID is if you have a DOM. Using the DOM parser, you can convert `unformattedString` into a DOM then retrieve the correct element. Otherwise, you'll have to insert the newly created `div` into the main DOM. I suppose the final alternative would be to parse it and generate the nodes yourself but then you're just rewriting `DOMParser`.

Comment: You'd have to use a string search on the unformatted string.  But that's not necessarily sensible.

Comment: guys, hes asking for a **DOM node** that is not attached, not a html string...

Comment: @MikeC so I can have multiple DOMs?

Comment: @userqwert Sure, you have the main DOM where everything is rendered then you can create other DOMs in memory.

Comment: @MikeC neat thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Create a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), attach your node to it and use `getElementById`:

   ```
   var domFragment = new DocumentFragment();
   domFragment.appendChild(div);
   var elem = domFragment.getElementById("yourid");
   ```
2. Use [query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/QuerySelector):

   ```
   var elem = div.querySelector("#yourid");
   ```

Comment: var elem = div.querySelector("#yourid"); is what I was looking for! thanks

Comment: @userqwert How about marking this as the answer then?