# how to check the actual DOM node using react enzyme

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, enzyme

Is there a way to get the actual DOM node so I can the query it with the Dom api as opposed to being required to use enzyme's api, it's just for edge cases where for example I need to assert things about the dom node itself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `wrapper.getDOMNode()`

[Enzyme docs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/getDOMNode.md)

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps you are looking for enzyme's [instance()](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html)?

```
const wrapper = mount(<input type="text" defaultValue="hello"/>)
console.log(wrapper.instance().value); // 'hello'
```

**PS:**

`instance()` should give you a `ReactComponent`, from which you can use ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ReactComponent) to get a DOMNode. However, when I did that, like the following, it was the exact same object as `wrapper.instance()`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
const wrapper = mount(<input type="text" defaultValue="sup"/>)
console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(wrapper.instance()) == wrapper.instance()) // true
```

I don't understand why that is. If you `console.log()` either one of those, you'll see a `HTMLInputElement`, but it will contain lots of non-native DOM node looking stuff:

```
HTMLInputElement {
  '__reactInternalInstance$yt1y6akr6yldi': 
   ReactDOMComponent {
     _currentElement: 
      { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
        type: 'input',
        key: null,
        ref: null,
        props: [Object],
        _owner: [Object],
        _store: {} },
```

Comment: When I tried your technique, it seemed to work as expected.  In other words, `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(wrapper.instance()) != wrapper.instance()`. FWIW, I'm using React 15 and Enzyme 2.3.0.

Comment: I wonder if it's because I was using jsdom (or, I THINK I was. Foolish I don't have a permalink to the code I ran). Are you using jsdom?

Comment: Yes, I am using jsdom 9.1.0 - sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: This applies only for the root wrapper (of the React component `mount()`ed or `shallow()`ed). See @tonyjmnz' answer for a more broadly-applicable solution.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same problem.  In my case, I was testing something built with `react-aria-modal`, which renders the overlay div in a different part of the DOM than the initial element rendered with `mount()`.  In order to test that this renders properly, I needed to look more globally at the DOM.  For this, I used the `attachTo` option of `render()` to ensure that my test DOM looks like it should in a real browser.  [Here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/detach.md) is a good general description of the technique from the docs.

Depending on what you need, you can use Tyler Collier's approach for more local parts of the DOM (`findDOMNode` using `instance()`) or mine for a more global view.

Here's a sample spec for my use case, showing how to setup/use/teardown the mock DOM:

```
import MyModalComponent from '../components/my-modal-component'
import React from 'react'
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

describe('<MyModalComponent /> Component', function(){

  let wrapper

  beforeEach(function(){
    window.document = jsdom('')
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
  })

  afterEach(function(){
    wrapper.detach()
    window.document = jsdom('')
  })

  it('renders the modal closed by default', () => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <MyModalComponent prop1={"foo"}
                        prop2={"bar"}
      />, { attachTo: document.body.firstChild }
    )
    expect(wrapper.html()).to.contain('Content in component')
    expect(document.body.innerHTML).to.not.contain('Content in overlay')
  })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a DOM using jsdom, something like this:

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.document = doc;
global.window = doc.defaultView;
```

Then you can use enzyme's [mount()](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md) to render whatever you wish to test.

You can then assert against the style you are looking for:

`expect(wrapper).to.have.style("display", "none");`

Comment: I am using mount which uses jsdom as I understand, already but how would you get the actual wrapper's DOM node so I can use the dom api? for example to query className but *not* using prop('className')

Comment: There may be a better way, but you could always call `.html()` on the element, and then use something like `DOMParser()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use soemething like :

```
const dialog = component.find(Modal);
let modal = dialog.node._modal;
modal.getDialogElement().querySelector('#saveBtn')
```

based on the test for Modal in react-bootstrap web site

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/test/ModalSpec.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out whole DOM,

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
console.log("DOM tree for humans", wrapper.text());
```