# Testing grommet Layer component

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme, grommet

I'm using grommet with react to render my application's UI. I have a Layer component shown when user click a button. Everything works fine but I don't know how to test Layer's children.
I'm using enzyme, mocha and chai as test suite. 
This is code the code of my component:

```
<Layer align="right" closer>
    <Header size="large" justify="between" align="center">
        <Button icon={<CloseIcon />} plain={true} onClick={ props.hide }/>
    </Header>
    <Section key={index} pad={{ horizontal: 'large', vertical: 'small' }}>
        { props.list }
    </Section>   
</Layer>
```

and this is my test:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
const layer = wrapper.find(Layer);

//this works
expect(layer).to.have.length.of(1);

const section = layer.find(Section);

//and this fails
expect(section).to.have.length.of(1);
```

Looking at the rendered component in the application, I found that grommet render his Layer component in this way:

```
<Layer><span style={{ display: 'none'}}></span></Layer>
```

Anyone can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code for the layer component](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/blob/master/src/js/components/Layer.js#L297), you will see that it returns the span that you posted in the render method.  It's not until the component has mounted that the [layer's contents will be rendered](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/blob/master/src/js/components/Layer.js#L162-L163) by calling the `addLayer` method in the `Layer` class.

I believe that you should use enzyme's [`mount`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md) function in order to test that the Layer is properly rendering its content since you will want the `componentDidMount` method to be called.

Comment: I try to use mount instead of shallow, but result is the same.
I found the span not in the testing environment, but inspecting my page with chrome developers react Tools while application is running.
I also notice that layer's content are rendered outside the entire application, but it doesn't make sense!

Comment: Hey @alessia, that's correct.  Looking through the [code](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/blob/master/src/js/components/Layer.js#L218-L233), it looks like the layer is added to the dom after mount so the result of the test is correct.

Comment: I found an answer that contains instructions for testing the actual DOM using Enzyme and JSDom.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38424409/5948656).

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve this issue by mocking grommet Layer component:

```
jest.mock("grommet/components/Layer", () => (props) => props.children);
```