# Can't set input element value in Enzyme

Tags: javascript, testing, enzyme

In my test, I have this:

```
let fromInput = wrapper.find('#starting-address').getElement();
fromInput.value = 'Foo';
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot add property value, object is not extensible.

I'm trying to test a button I have which, on clicking, should clear the value of the input element (id: 'starting-address'). I was planning on asserting that `fromInput.value === 'foo'` before simulating the click, and `fromImput.value === ''` after clicking.

Comment: Are you `mount`ed or `shallow` rendered the component?

Comment: I'm using `mount`

Answer (score 3):

This worked with me:

```
it("Successfully add an employee to the employees' list when the form submitted",function(){
   const wrapper = mount(<App/>);
   const addEmpWapper = wrapper.find('AddEmployee');
   addEmpWapper.find("#txtName").getDOMNode().value = "Youki";
   addEmpWapper.find("#txtImgUrl").getDOMNode().value = "ImageUrl1";
   addEmpWapper.find("#txtDesc").getDOMNode().value = "Cute baby.";

   const form = addEmpWapper.find('form');
   form.simulate("submit");
   // I already had 3 employees in the app's states bag.
   expect(wrapper.state().employees).to.have.lengthOf(4);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [instance()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html) instead:

```
const formInput = wrapper.find('#starting-address').instance();
formInput.value = 'Foo';
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723238/how-to-check-the-actual-dom-node-using-react-enzyme), for more details.

Comment: The docs says it can only be called on a wrapper instance that is also the root instance though?

Comment: I think this is b/c of `shallow()` ( as in they example). If you do `mount()` - I don't see the reason why not to use it.