# Why is DOMParser not preserving inline styles of parsed DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domparser

I am simply trying to parse and append a JavaScript string as a DOM element. I have found two quick ways to do this, one of which is using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) as seen in [this popular SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104237/1464112). Both methods work, however, the `DOMParser` approach for some reason is not respecting the inline  styles I define - even though both methods inject the **exact same** dynamic markup. Consider the following...

```
<div></div>
```

---

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]

// ---- case 1 ---------------

var parser = new DOMParser();
var node = parser.parseFromString('<p style="color: red">foo</p>', 'text/xml').firstChild;
parent.appendChild(node);

// ---- case 2 ---------------

var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML= '<p style="color: red">foo</p>';
var node2 = wrapper.firstChild;
parent.appendChild(node2);
```

Each method injects the node accordingly and the DOM reflects the following...

```
<div>
    <p style="color: red">foo</p>
    <p style="color: red">foo</p>
</div>
```

However, only the last is red! Any idea what can possibly be going on here?

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLnesqrb/) - reproduction demo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you didn't set a namespace. `style` attributes don't have any special meaning in XML:

```js
var str = '<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="color: red">foo</p>';
var node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/xml').firstChild;
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Comment: aw snap! Nice one. That does indeed explain why thank you very much :) The other solution by @Deep does work as well, however involved a whole html document and a bit more traversing

Comment: Just so I understand, without the `xmln=`, does the browser not know that the parsed text is HTML at all? In the OP Fiddle, Firefox doesn't realize the `p` is a `p` (No browser styles are applied, like margin).

Comment: @AndyM Yes, since the parser parses as `text/xml`, elements do not have the semantics of HTML. In the DOM, the `p` will only be an `Element` instance, not a `HTMLElement` one, so it won't have properties like `style`.

Answer (score 1):

CSS will be applied if you use the method like below.

```
var node = parser.parseFromString('<p style="color: red">foo</p>', 'text/html').firstChild.lastChild.firstChild;
```

here i am using 'text/html' As per the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser
using text/html returns a HTMLDocument.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wLnesqrb/8/

Comment: hmm, that method seems to be injecting a whole html document if you inspect the nodes. Either way that can be worked around, and yes I can see the style. Any idea why the dynamic node using `text/xml` isn't styled even though it should be according to inspecting the DOM?

Comment: This wraps the paragraph inside a `html` and `body` elements. `firstChild` will be that `html` element.

Comment: +1, after checking out the answer from @Oriol, I have a total understanding of _why_ this is happening regarding the styles but this did help, thank you!

Comment: @scniro you are welcome, however you already got the answer but i edited mine just to resolve your traversing issue to reach the <p> element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '<p style="color: red">foo</p>';
var frag = new DocumentFragment();
frag.innerHTML = str;
document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

But adding namespaces is safer if you want your code to work in XML documents too and not just HTML.