# Copy and assign native method of document object

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to perform the document.getElementById() method on the String object.

---

```js
String.prototype.getElementById = document.getElementById;
test = new String('<p id="para1">Irgendein Text</p>');
console.log(test.getElementById("para1"))
```

The above attempt returns: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Is there a way to perform the getElementByID method on a string?

**Edit:**

Thanks works like a charm:

```
var test = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<dummy/>', 'text/xml');
test.getElementsByTagName('dummy')[0].innerHTML = '<p id="para1">Irgendein Text</p>';
console.log(doc.getElementById('para1'));
```

Returns `<p id="para1">Irgendein Text</p>`

Comment: I can understand (a little bit) wanting to be able to say `someId.getElementById()`, although it seems to be just a minor improvement over `document.getElementById(someId)`, but your example stumps me--you somehow want to find an element by passing in a string of HTML from which the ID is somehow to be extracted? Are you sure you don't just want to do `document.querySelector('p#para1')`?

Comment: Yes, i realized that my code has no applications, i will use document.querySelector() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is not a document, so it can't be traversed by DOM methods like `getElementById`. It sounds like you want to treat a string as a dom selection and then run a query on it. `querySelector` lets you run a query on a chunk of DOM or the whole document so you can use that. `document.querySelector('#id')` will yield the same set of elements as `document.getElementById('id')`.

An easy way to turn a string into DOM is to set it to the `innerHTML` of another element. So

```
var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML= '<p id="para1">Irgendein Text</p>';
console.log(wrapper.querySelector('#para1')); // your p tag
```

See also
[Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)