# Angular2 way of converting plain text to url (anchor links)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I sometimes have a component that can receive text like this:

> text www.website.com

But I would like to convert it to a url if it is a link. Like this.

> text [www.website.com](http://example.com)

I read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/4031815) that suggests using 3rd party libs such as [anchorme](https://github.com/alexcorvi/anchorme.js). Is there anywway to do it the angular2 way?

Comment: What's the problem with this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are numerous problems with using simple regexes to modify HTML content.

Here's an approach that uses the [linkifyjs](http://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/docs/) module, which you need to `npm install`. Do notice that the input is considered plain text, while output is HTML text.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import linkifyStr from 'linkifyjs/string';

@Pipe({name: 'linkify'})
export class LinkifyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(str: string): string {
    return str ? linkifyStr(str, {target: '_system'}) : str;
  }
}
```

NB: If you need to specify the `target` attributes, add eg. `{target: '_system'}` as a second parameter to `linkifyStr`.

Comment: thank you for this great library 
but in typescript cannot include 'linkifyjs/string' and i cannot found any typescript support for library

Comment: i think we need to bind result to innerHtml if we are using Angular2 
````
<div [innerHTML]="message | linkify "></div>
```

Comment: You can import the lib like this: `var linkifyString = require('linkifyjs/string');` and use in the same way, without any typescript support.

Comment: It didn't work for me at first, I kept on receiving `string_1.default is not a function` error. Eventually I've found that changing the import statement to `import * as linkifyString from 'linkifyjs/string';` resolved the issue!

Answer (score 13):

Okay so to make a pipe you would make a pipe component consisting of

```
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';



    @Pipe({name: 'linkify'})
    export class LinkifyPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(link: string): string {
        return this.linkify(link);
      }

      private linkify(plainText): string{
        let replacedText;
        let replacePattern1;
        let replacePattern2;
        let replacePattern3;

        //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
        replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
        replacedText = plainText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

        //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
        replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
        replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

        //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
        replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim;
        replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');

        return replacedText;
       }
    }
```

then import this like u would a directive, pass it to the

```
pipes: [LinkifyPipe]
```

and interpolate like this

```
{{url | linkify}}
```

Comment: It's returns the "<a href='www.google.com'>" as a string not working like dom element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements    there is a JavaScript DOMParser that will convert HTML to JavaScript.  I ran into this exact issue recently and you cannot cheat a dom element using strings

Comment: i think we need to bind result to innerHtml if we are using Angular2 
````
<div [innerHTML]="message | linkify "></div>
```

Comment: At the start of the linkify() function, add: `plainText = plainText.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">","&gt;");` to stop injection attempts and complaints in the console because of that. Then to use bind to innerHTML as Amr mentioned

Answer (score 9):

You should check angular-linky https://github.com/dzonatan/angular-linky

```
<span [innerHTML]="yourText | linky"></span>
```

Comment: Best for Angular.

Comment: The key here for me was the innerHTML. I already can form my URL....

Answer (score 8):

you should use this pipe in this way:

`<div [innerHtml]="note.title | linkify"></div>`

Answer (score 3):

I have searched for a solution but to no avail. I needed to extent the requirement to handle Angular routing [routerLink] and external links with [innerHTML] without the need for 3rd party libs.

**My solution (summary):**

Angular 2, Angular 5 - User click events/event handling for dynamic [innerHTML] generated content using pipe and directive to generate and converting plain text to click urls e.g #hashtags,  @Handle, @Mention, #routerLink #href and #mailto etc

**Plunker demo:**
https://embed.plnkr.co/68lZFY/

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Angular - Dynamic content click event</h1>
                        <p>Angular 2, Angular 5, Typescript - User click events/event handling for dynamic [innerHTML] generated content using pipe and directive to generate and converting plain text to click urls e.g #hashtags,  @Handle, @Mention, #routerLink #href and #mailto etc</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li *ngFor="let item of theList; let $index=index;" [innerHTML]="item | parseUrl" [dynamicContent]="currentView"></li>
                        <ul>`
})
export class AppComponent {
     theList:Array;

        constructor() {
                this.theList = [
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur @adet dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam',
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing http://google.com sed do eiusmod tempor #incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam',
                    'Lorem http://google.com ipsum dolor #sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt gna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam',
                    'Lorem ipsum @dolor sit amet, consectetur @adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod @tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam',
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, smod tempor incididunt #ut labore et dolore @magna #aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam',
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam',
                    'Lorem ipsum @dolor sit amet, #consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor http://google.com enim ad minim veniam'
                ];
        }

}
```

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[dynamicContent]'
})
export class DynamicContent {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @Input('dynamicContent') dynamicContent: string;

    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(e) {

        if (e.target.classList.contains('handle-link')) {
            let link: string = e.target.innerHTML;

            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            alert("/search/handle/" + link.trim());

            //this.router.navigateByUrl("/search/handle/" + link.trim(), { skipLocationChange: false });

        } else if (e.target.classList.contains('hashtag-link')) {
            let link: string = e.target.innerHTML;

            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

             alert("/search/hashtag/" + link.trim());

            //this.router.navigateByUrl("/search/hashtag/" + link.trim(), { skipLocationChange: false }); 

        }

    }

}
```

**Pipe**

```
export class ParseUrl implements PipeTransform {

    urls: any = /(\b(https?|http|ftp|ftps|Https|rtsp|Rtsp):\/\/[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;-]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim; // Find/Replace URL's in text  
    hashtags: any = /(^|\s)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig; // Find/Replace #hashtags in text   
    mentions: any = /(^|\s)(@[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig; // Find/Replace @Handle/Mentions in text    
    emails: any = /(\S+@\S+\.\S+)/gim; // Find/Replace email addresses in text

    transform(text: string) {
        return this.parseUrl(text);
    }

    private parseUrl(text: string) {
        // Find/Replace URL's in text
        if (text.match(this.urls)) {
                text = text.replace(this.urls, function replacer($1, $2, $3) {
                        let url: any = $1;
                        let urlClean: any = url.replace("" + $3 + "://", "");

                        return "<a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + urlClean + "</a>";
                });
        }

        // Find/Replace @Handle/Mentions in text
        if (text.match(this.hashtags)) {
            text = text.replace(this.hashtags, "<a href=\"/search/hashtag/$2\" class=\"hashtag-link\">$1$2</a>");
        }

        // Find/Replace #hashtags in text
        if (text.match(this.mentions)) {
            text = text.replace(this.mentions, "<a href=\"/search/handle/$2\" class=\"handle-link\">$1$2</a>");
        }

        // Find/Replace email addresses in text
        if (text.match(this.emails)) {
                text = text.replace(this.emails, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>");
        }

        return text;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is how I did it leaving answer hope it helps someone else:

So I'm using a function to linkify my plaint text

```
private linkify(plainText): string{
    let replacedText;
    let replacePattern1;
    let replacePattern2;
    let replacePattern3;

    //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    replacedText = plainText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

    //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
    replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

    //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
    replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim;
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');

    return replacedText;
}
```

But this returns a string with html encoding so if I use in with `<p>{{example}}</p>` it will return full encoding (inlcuding  anchor tags and html).

So now I use angular2 builtin html binding:

This gives me the solution

Comment: There are ways to dynamically inject observable DOM elements post render but its unsafe and heavy. Your best bet is to use a pipe. I know they can be scary, but you use the pipe on the interpolated value, it will manipulate it and spit it back out as u wish. Let me know if this is something youre interested in, ill throw down an example in the answer box and we can work this out.

Comment: Functions and pipes are essentially the same. The pipe will be modular and cleaner however

Comment: hey @MarkAcosta if you want to include it as an answer your welcome, I can accept your answer once its working