# Angular4 add custom pipe to async value

Tags: angular, pipe, linkify

Short explanation of my problem:

Till now i had this line of code in my html:

```
<pre class="preFormattedText" [innerHtml]="(project | async)?.Remarks"></pre>
```

Then i found the useful plugin [Linkify](http://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/docs/) and this post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276617/angular2-way-of-converting-plain-text-to-url-anchor-links). So i added a new pipeComponent:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'linkify' })
export class LinkifyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(link: string): string {
        return this.linkify(link);
    }
private linkify(plainText): string {
    let replacedText;
    let replacePattern1;
    let replacePattern2;
    let replacePattern3;

    //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    replacedText = plainText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

    //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
    replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

    //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
    replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim;
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');

    return replacedText;
  }
}
```

So i updated my original line of code to

```
<pre class="preFormattedText" [innerHtml]="(project | async)?.Remarks | linkify"></pre>
```

But now i get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

and this section of my code gets highlighted

```
<h3 class="subtitleH3">{{ this.localizationService.localized['globalComment'] }}</h3>
<div>
    <pre class="preFormattedText" [innerHtml]="(project | async)?.Remarks | linkify"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first or second replace returns null. Can you find out which one?

Comment: looks like your pipe is not getting value of plainText args, if you want to transform your async data why not doing (project | async | linkify)

Comment: @RobinDijkhof if i set a breakpoint inside the pipe the breakpoint gets called twice.. once the given obj is null and once its the content which i want to linkify... i guess the reason is getting the content async?

Comment: Yes I think so. Build in a simple null check.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof thank you, i did that

Answer (score 0):

found it, had to implement a simple null check