# Parse a HTML string to DOM and return the DOM in the Express(node js) response

Tags: express

I wrote a javascript(nodejs+express) program to download a html document from a given url.
    I converted into a DOM object using parse5, jsdom, cherrio(only one). Now I need to send the response(the DOM object) to an ajax call. But when I try

```
var document = jsdom(data); //can use any of these three

var $ = cheerio.load(data);

var document3 = parse5.parse(data);

return res.send({'data':document3});
```

It gives an error 'converting circular structure to json', which is obvious because I'm trying to convert a DOM object to JSON.

***My requirement is to parse the HTML and send the DOM as response because I need to use the DOM on client side.*** 
    What should be approach?

Comment: Have you tried just send the DOM (assume you have done some process on it) as a string and convert the DOM string back to a DOM on client side? Obviously Json won't work for the DOM obj.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just send the DOM (assume you have done some process on it) as a string and convert the DOM string back to a DOM on client side? Obviously Json won't work for the DOM obj.

Comment: I didn't try that. But is there a way of converting string back to DOM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements