# removeClass before html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable which has two classes. I am wanting to remove the `small` class before the `html()` pushes the div to `DOM`.

As of right now, the div is rendering with the `small` class. I am wanting that to be removed.

I have tried switching the order of the `removeClass` to place it before the `html()`, but that didn't work.

```
$('#review').removeClass('small').html(prev);
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

```js
var prev = "<div class='big small'>Hello</div>";
$('#review').html(prev).removeClass('small');
```

```css
.big {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.small {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="review"></div>
```

### UPDATE

I tried to make my question really basic for simplicity, but it turns out, the array I had in my actual code made this more complex.

```js
$('body').on('change', '.option-check', function() {
  var calSelectionImg = [];
  $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function() {
    calSelectionImg.push($(this).data('calendar-img'));
  });
  $('#pg-img-review').html(calSelectionImg);
});
```

```css
.cal-selected-img {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.small {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="option-check" data-cal-choice="<div class='cal-selected-img small'>Hello</div>">

<input type="checkbox" class="option-check" data-cal-choice="<div class='cal-selected-img small'>Goodbye</div>">

<div id="pg-img-review" class="margin15"></div>
```

Comment: Why create the element with the `small` clas in the first place ? Or is this only some excerpt of something more complex?

Comment: @krtek More complex. I just made a simple version to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying `#review`, not your new code. So, I added `appendTo`. It's a minor restructure, but it fixes the issues with minimal complications.

```js
var prev = "<div class='big small'>Hello</div>";
$(prev).removeClass('small').appendTo("#review");
```

```css
.big {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.small {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="review"></div>
```

Comment: Could anyone point me to anything that would be helpful to get only one selection choice to show at once? Right now, it just keep populating selections, if I click on different checkboxes.

Comment: In future, you need only flag once. We will know to remove all the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you've given, the HTML in `prev` is just a string. You need to parse it into a DOM object before you can call a function such as `.removeClass()` on it.

jQuery provides a number of options for parsing HTML elements, but as a vanilla JS over jQuery proponent, I often favour [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104251/1532795) particular approach:

```
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.innerHtml = "<p class='small'>The string of HTML</p>";
var parsedElement = tempDiv.firstChild;
```

I can then call the jQuery method `parsedElement.removeClass("small")` or Vanilla JS `parsedElement.classList.remove("small")` to successfully remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var prev = "<div class='big small'>Hello</div>";
$('#review').html(prev).find('.small').removeClass('small');
```

```css
.big {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.small {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="review"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need this:

```
var prev = "<div class='big small'>Hello</div>";
$('#review').html(prev);
$(".big").removeClass('small');
```

Add your DIV first, and then remove the class you don't need later.

Don't worry

```
$(".big").removeClass('small');
```

would cause any problem. If there is no CLASS [small], the DOM will ignore the js.

That's all.O(∩_∩)O~