# Javascript pull content from variable by id

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pull content inside a variable using plain java script.
I am trying to get only part of the variable with an id.
In this example I am trying to pull only part of html with id ‘container’.

My fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/a2ngc9jv/2/

```
var htmlPage = `
<html>
<div>
testing but not required
</div>
  <div id="container">
    <p>
     i want to pull this whole block from parent 
    </p>
    <p>
      test 2
    </p>
  </div>

</html>`;

console.log(htmlPage.getElementById("container"))
console.log(document.getElementById("container"))
```

Comment: That isn't going to work unless you convert `htmlPage` into a DOM element.

Comment: if you're HTML is just a javascript string, there is no such `getElementById` method you can call on it. Also, it's not clear what you mean by "pulling" a part.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the browser or in something like Node?

Comment: any other option to pull substring?

Comment: I am using a ajax call and it results html page. I am trying to cut only a block from that page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in the Browser you can use `DOMparser()` to turn this into a real dom object, then you can call the method you want to get elements from it.

```js
var htmlPage = `
<html>
<div>
testing but not required
</div>
  <div id="container">
    <p>
     i want to pull this whole block from parent
    </p>
    <p>
      test 2
    </p>
  </div>

</html>`;


var parser=new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(htmlPage, "text/html");

console.log(htmlDoc.getElementById("container"))
console.log(htmlDoc.getElementById("container").innerHTML)
```

Comment: it says dom parser is not defined. Do I have to add something else?

Comment: @Kurkula what browser are you running this on? Does the above snipper run for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means…aren't you using chrome to look at the jsfiddle?

Comment: i used var parser=new DOMParser(); var htmlDoc=.... After using var it started working.

Answer (score 1):

htmlPage is a string not a document node.  However it's easy to put it into one:

```js
var htmlPage = `
<html>
<div>
testing but not required
</div>
  <div id="container">
    <p>
     i want to pull this whole block from parent 
    </p>
    <p>
      test 2
    </p>
  </div>

</html>`;

// it might not be "allowed" to put a html tag inside a div but it works for this purpose.
var n = document.createElement('div');
n.innerHTML = htmlPage;

var content = n.querySelector('#container p:first-child').innerHTML;

console.log(content);
```

Comment: There's also `DOMParser`, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962)