# SVG objects within Bootstrap tab get unloaded when changing active tab

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have some SVG objects displayed within bootstrap tabs

```
<object
 className="test_card"
 type="image/svg+xml"
 data={"http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/card_layout.svg"}>
    Your browser does not support SVGs
</object>
```

The problem is that everytime I change the active tab, there is a short delay before the SVG images get displayed, like the page is loading them.

If I use `<img/>` to display the SVGs, they stay loaded and show instantly when I activate the tab, but I need to be able to modify some of the SVG content dynamically, so I can't use that.

How can I keep the SVG pictures loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution. Instead of objects, I load the svg file into a string, and inline it dynamically in my html.

I get the **SVG** string with a jquery AJAX call:

```
$.get("/static/images/cardLayout.svg?",
            (data) => {
                svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data.documentElement);
            }
        );
```

This gives me the string representing the SVG.

---

**From there, in react, I am using:**

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: svgString}} />
```

Which displays the same thing that using `<object>`, except that the svg is now inlined and doesn't get unloaded each time I change the active tab.

---

**If you're not using React**

I didn't test it, but with pure JS I think you can transform a string into a dom element using the answer to this question: [Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)

Answer (score 0):

The `svg` images and icons are slow. You need to convert them in `web fonts` to improve performance. Check out this article for more details.
http://frozeman.de/blog/2013/08/why-is-svg-so-slow/

Comment: Thanks for the article. It's interesting but I don't want the SVG pictures to load faster, I want them to stay loaded so that it displays instantly