# Tool to Convert HTML into JavaScript (.createElement)?

Tags: javascript

I have the HTML but I want to create it programatically. I know how to do it with JavaScript's `.createElement` `.appendChild` methods but it's time consuming. I can't find such a conversion tool online.

Does anyone know if there is a tool, an online tool, to take my HTML snippet and generate the JavaScript required to add that to my document?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use innerHTML to just add whole snippet. Or [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to append or prepend at any point in your document

Comment: Yea, I knew about `innerHTML` but none of the professional scripting I've seen uses it. For some reason they always seem to use `.appendChild` and `.createElement`. This type of conversion tool seems useful to only me apparently...? It's a time sink to write the script to append a large chunk of HTML....

Comment: innerHTML is actually quite fast, because you save some function calls and browsers are good in parsing HTML. Even jQuery uses innerHTML in `.html()` if possible and to convert HTML strings to elements.