# How to add a class to an element in an HTML string without using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have an html string that looks like this :

```
'<p>Hello</p><p>I would like to schedule a meeting with you.</p>
 <a class="button button--blue" href="#">
   <button class="button 
      button--blue">Schedule meeting
   </button>
 </a>
 <p>See you soon.</p> 
 <p>baher</p>',
```

How can i access these elements individually to add a class to them without using jQuery?
please note that i'm working on the server side so stuff like `document` and `window` are not accessible

Comment: Which one specifically?

Comment: It's just a string so you can't "access" it until it's interpreted by the DOM. to do so easily you can use `document.body.innerHTML = your_string` and then just use regular querying methods like `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="hello">Hello</p><p>I would like to schedule a meeting with you.</p>
<a class="button button--blue" href="#">
<button class="button button--blue">Schedule meeting
</button>
</a>
<p>See you soon.</p> 
<p>baher</p>'

<script>
var hello = document.getElementById("hello");
hello.classList.add("mystyle");
</script>
```

Comment: He is working with a string, not a DOM element. Because of that, this method (even if its right) won't work in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

you can access `#document` methods on server side as well just you need to properly link files . on whatever server side language you are working there is a method to add dynamic data  lets say you are working on node.js with handlebars templating engine then you can do something like this

```
<div {{if conditn_true}} class="anyname" {{/if}}></div>
```

if you are using php then

```
<div class="<?php something related to class ?>" ?> ></div>
```

other 
dom methods

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    element.classList.add("mystyle");
```

hope this helps...be more specific on what exactly you are trying to achieve by mentioning some code snippet so that we can further help you