# Remove specific tags from content and keep shortcodes

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

How to remove all HTML div Tags from content and keep all shortcodes. the script bellow remove all div tag and shortcodes.

```js
var html  = '<p>[my_shortcode post_id="2451"]';
    html += '<div class="parent-div-01"><div class="extras"><div>div lvl 3</div>line 01<br>line 01<br></div></div></p>';
    html += '<p>[my_shortcode post_id="1542"]';
    html += '<div class="parent-div-02"><div class="extras"><div>div lvl 3</div>line 01<br>line 01<br></div></div></p>';

function shortcode_constrict(html) {  
  return html.replace( /<div.*?<\/div>/g, "" );
}
console.log(shortcode_constrict(html));
```

Comment: You probably want to replace `.*` with `.*?` in your regexp (making the quantifier *lazy*). Should the `<p>`s remain there? On another note, using [DOM parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements) would probably be cleaner since this looks like a HTML string.

Comment: @Jeto i want to remove only div tags.

Comment: @Jeto Sorry, that work only with div first level but not work with div inside another div. I modified the script above.

Comment: See below answer. Using DOM parsing should be way more efficient/appropriate for this as I mentioned in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DOM parsing:

```js
var html  = '<p>[my_shortcode post_id="2451"]';
    html += '<div class="my-div-01"><div class="my-div-01">Content div 01</div></div></p>';
    html += '<p>[my_shortcode post_id="1542"]';
    html += '<div class="my-div-02"><div class="my-div-02">Content div 01</div></div></p>';

function shortcode_constrict(html) {
  // Load the HTML string as XML, wrap it in a <root> tag as a XML doc needs one
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<root>' + html + '</root>', 'text/xml');
  
  // Remove all div elements
  doc.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(div) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
  });
  
  // Return the modified document's HTML content
  return doc.documentElement.innerHTML;
}

console.log(shortcode_constrict(html));
```