# How to get element from HTML stored in variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am running an API to retrieve email from external system. I managed to get HTML code from the returned JSON and store it in a variable. Now, I would like to run some further operations on this HTML - for example get all elements with 
`[data-type="whatever"]`.
 It would be easy in html document:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="whatever"]');
```

However the HTML document I want to work with is stored in the variable so the code I write in API does not recognise it as a document. How can I do it? Any suggestions with vanilla JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting HTML string into DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements)

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this.

```js
let rawDoc = '<html><head><title>Working with elements</title></head><body><div id="div1">The text above has been created dynamically.</div></body></html>'

let doc = document.createElement('html');
doc.innerHTML = rawDoc;
let div1 = doc.querySelector('#div1');
console.log(div1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you use `innerHTML`? or maybe I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: I feel like if you expanded this with explanation + pos code snippet as example, it would make for a much better answer :)

Comment: I thought so too, but the OP didn't give any useful code snippets, hence I don't know how to exactly give a useful example without going out of context

Comment: You just need to provide vanilla JS code - not a copy/paste solution - the answer is the same based on principle :) but I like your hesitance! Tis better to wait until you're 100% certain :)

Comment: Don't know if this makes enough sense, but I'd like OP to point out what he/she needs exactly:

https://jsfiddle.net/3w29rcap/

Comment: I run API in postman and to retrieve email's html I do the following:

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var emailHtml = jsonData.views.html.content;

Email's HTML is stored in emailHtml variable and typeof is a string. It starts with:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> <html>
And ends with:
</html>

Is it possible to convert it into the document that if I use:

var x = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="whatever"]')
console.log(x);

Postman console outputs all elements with this query selector?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working without a document you have 2 options.

```
1. Use regex to get what you need (something like /<.+>.+ data-type="whatever".+<\/.+>/gi) should do (but for an exact match you may need to make something better).


2. Insert the html in a hidden part of the dom and select what you need from it (like in Zohir answer - he provided a good example).
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following code with angular to store whole html content in a variable and pass it as argument to call API.

`var htmlBody = $('<div/>').append($('#htmlBody').clone()).html();`

This might work for you as i was working on sending email to pass invoice template so try this.