# manipulating array values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array

```
var my_arry =
      { "Description": "Actual Opening stock"
      , "Fri 05-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='600'>"
      , "Mon 01-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='200'>"
      , "Thu 04-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='500'>"
      }
```

I want loop through this and format the array like bellow

```
var my_arry = 
      { "Description": "Actual Opening stock"
      , "Fri 05-Aug" : "600"
      , "Mon 01-Aug" : "200"
      , "Thu 04-Aug" : "500"
      }
```

basically get the value from input tag

I have use the following but did not work

```
$.each( my_arry, function( key, value ) {
                    console.log(value.find('input').val())
                 });
```

any other way I can do this

Comment: Your `my_arry` - fair enough is actually an **Object Literal** and it's also an **invalid one** since properties have spaces (`Fri 05-Aug`) but are not wrapped into quotes. So yeah, fix it and call it... call it `my_obby`- Still your question makes no sense. Loop what input elements?

Comment: Your code is invalid, you don't have an array but an object, please post the html and a [mcve]

Comment: If you're copy/pasting from the console or something, do yourself (and us) a favor and use `console.log(JSON.stringify(my_arry, null, 2))`, then copy and paste the result.

Comment: i have edit my code

Comment: @HereticMonkey Hi i have edit my code

Comment: It looks like the value of those properties are actually **strings**, not elements, so you'd have to parse them as such with `$(value)`.

Comment: First you have to convert HTML string to DOM element by using DOMParser.
Like: new DOMParser().parseFromString(value,"text/html")).find('input').val()

Comment: check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104237/540195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```js
var my_arry = { "Description": "Actual Opening stock",
                     "Fri 05-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='600'>",
                     "Mon 01-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='200'>",
                     "Thu 04-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='500'>",
                   }

var arr_new = {};

$.each( my_arry, function( key, value ) {
                if(key != "Description" ){ 
                        arr_new[key] = $(value).val();
                } else {
                        arr_new[key] = value;
                } });

console.log(arr_new)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much exactly what i wanted. thanks for the much help

Comment: @kanishkakumarasiri np bro.

Comment: what if i have two object array ? i mean two index in same array

Comment: Wrap the same code in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

same with native JS (no jQuery)

```js
const my_arry =
        { "Description": "Actual Opening stock"
        , "Fri 05-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='600'>"
        , "Mon 01-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='200'>"
        , "Thu 04-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='500'>"
        } 

const parser = new DOMParser()

var rep = {}
for(let elm in my_arry)
  {
  if (elm === 'Description')
    {
    rep[elm] = my_arry[elm]
    }
   else
    {
    let doc  = parser.parseFromString(my_arry[elm], "text/html")
    rep[elm] =  doc.querySelector('input').value
    }
  }

console.log( rep )
```

other case for **real array** of objects

```js
const my_arry = 
  [ { "Description": "Actual Opening stock",   "Fri 05-Aug" : "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='600'>" } 
  , { "Description": "closing Opening stock ", "Fri 05-Aug" : "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='600'>" } 
  ]

const parser = new DOMParser()

for(let elm of my_arry)
  {
  let doc  = parser.parseFromString(elm['Fri 05-Aug'], "text/html")
  elm['Fri 05-Aug'] = doc.querySelector('input').value
  }

console.log( my_arry)
```

Comment: what if i have two object array ? i mean two index in same array

Comment: @kanishkakumarasiri what do you nean ? object and array are 2 differents things "object-array" doesn't exist anywhere. your `my_arry` is a js object, not a array, even if we can tranform or use it in a arry form. be more specific!

Comment: means like this const my_arry =
        { "Description": "Actual Opening stock"
        , "Fri 05-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='600'>"
        },
 { "Description": "closing Opening stock "
        , "Fri 05-Aug": "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='600'>"
        }

Comment: yes two entries

Comment: @kanishkakumarasiri in fact this not json valid => jsonlint.com I supose you use array of object with 2 entries (who are the same)   ?????
  
Please stop doing everything wrong, all computer languages have strict syntax rules, and you have to respect them. Explaining bases when the job for a technical solution is very unpleasant.