# How to extract the source of images inside class div in html response react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have regular expression for extracting the source of images in html string coming from json api in react native app, that works fine.
The output is in urls array:

```
var m,
urls = [],
str = '<img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg" />,
rex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\alt="First slide">/g;
      while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
          urls.push( m[1] );
      }
console.log(urls);  // ["http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg",...]
```

However I want rex that gets only the source of images inside class carousel-item :

```
str = '<div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg" />';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not married to using RegEx, you can [write the HTML string to an actual dom node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements), and then manipulate it that way.  For each string:

```js
var imgNodes = []
var str = '<img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg" />

var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML= str
var strAsDOMNode = wrapper.firstChild;
ingNodes.push(strAsDOMNode)
```

Then you can filter the ones that have 'carousel-item' in their classList:

```js
const sources = imgNodes
  .filter( node => node.classList.contains('carousel-item') === true )
  .map( node => node.src )
```

I know this doesn't use RegEx but it does accomplish your goal.

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer but document.createElement never works in react native

Comment: you can use [react-native-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-html-parser)

Comment: I tried to use it but it gives me error with metro.