# <a> element doesn't redirect to another page and is not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web-component

I created a web-component in which I declared method which creates a copyright string:

```js
'<p>Copyright © 2020 Krzysztof Kaczyński<a href="https://www.google.com">. Policy terms</a></p>'
```

Then I am converting this string into `HTMLParagraphElement` and append to `footer` element.
When I open web browser I do not see any errors and I can see my copyright element.
If I inspect this element it also looks correct but if I click `<a>` part of this element nothing happens (but it should redirect to `https://www.google.com`).

- Why this `<a href="https://www.google.com">. Policy terms</a>` doesn't redirect to *https://www.google.com* after click ?
- How can I fix this ?

#### AppFooter component:

```js
export class AppFooter extends KKWebComponent implements KKAppFooter {
    public static TAG: string = `${CONSTANTS.TAG_PREFIX}-app-footer`;

    public readonly shadowRoot!: ShadowRoot;

    private footer!: HTMLElement;

    constructor() {
        super(template);
        this.getElementsReferences();
    }

    protected getElementsReferences(): void {
        this.footer = <HTMLElement>this.shadowRoot.querySelector('footer');
    }

    public setCopyright({ year, author, termsReferenceUrl }: CopyrightProps): void {
        const copyrightText: string = AppFooter.formattedCopyrights`Copyright © ${year} ${author}. Policy terms${termsReferenceUrl}`;
        this.footer.appendChild(new StringElementConverter().toElement(copyrightText));
    }

    private static formattedCopyrights(strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: string[]): string {
        const policyTermsUrlText: string = `<a href="${values[values.length - 1]}">${strings[strings.length - 2]}</a>`;
        let formattedText: string = '<p>';
        for (let i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
            formattedText += `${strings[i]}${values[i]}`;
        }
        formattedText += `${policyTermsUrlText}</p>`;
        return formattedText;
    }
}
```

#### Element on website:

[image]

#### Inspected element:

[image]

#### Code snippet

```js
class StringElementConverter {
    constructor() {
        this.domParser = new DOMParser();
    }

    toElement(xmlString) {
        const parsedString = this.domParser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml').firstElementChild;
        if (parsedString == null) {
            throw new Error(`This xml string ${xmlString} is not parsable to Node`);
        }
        return parsedString;
    }
}

const template = `
<footer>
  <slot name="prepend"></slot>
  <slot name="center"></slot>
  <slot name="append"></slot>
</footer>
`;

class AppFooter extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = template;
        this.getElementsReferences();
        this.setCopyright({
            year: '2020',
            author: 'Krzysztof Kaczyński',
            termsReferenceUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
        });
    }

    getElementsReferences() {
        this.footer = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('footer');
    }

    setCopyright({ year, author, termsReferenceUrl }) {
        const copyrightText = this.formattedCopyrights`Copyright © ${year} ${author}. Policy terms${termsReferenceUrl}`;
        this.footer.appendChild(new StringElementConverter().toElement(copyrightText));
    }

    formattedCopyrights(strings, ...values) {
        const policyTermsUrlText = `<a href="${values[values.length - 1]}">${strings[strings.length - 2]}</a>`;
        let formattedText = '<p>';
        for (let i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
            formattedText += `${strings[i]}${values[i]}`;
        }
        formattedText += `${policyTermsUrlText}</p>`;
        return formattedText;
    }
}
customElements.define('kk-app-footer', AppFooter);
```

```html
<kk-app-footer></kk-app-footer>
```

> If you need anything else let me know in comments

Comment: It should be `https://www.google.com` and not `www.google.com`.

Comment: @CherryDT this change didn't change anything

Comment: You most probably have a CSS issue. Can you select the text around it? If you cannot, it's because another element is on top of it. Show your CSS

Comment: @Ibu I can select this text (I added a screenshot to my question)

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński can you provide more information? This is a pretty simple link, and other than the missing protocol there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @AlexWayne What do you mean by more information ? Do you need a link to my repo ? Yes I know, it should work, but it doesn't. I can not explain why ?

Comment: Like @AlexWayne it's hard to debug a single link. Can you create a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) of this. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Add the codepen when you have a chance. No need to delete it.

Comment: Can you add a StackSnippet to your question above (ie. rather than a Codepen) please? The only possible thing I can think of is that your code is (somehow) `&lt;a href="www.google.com"&gt;. Policy terms&lt;/a&gt;`

Comment: Great. Thanks. Can you add a StackSnippet to your question above, rather than a Codepen, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.domParser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml')
```

You're not parsing your content as the right content type. You want:

```
this.domParser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/html')
```

I'm guessing that when you parse the content as XML instead of HTML, the browser doesn't think that `<a>` has any special meaning.

---

Working example:

```js
class StringElementConverter {
    constructor() {
        this.domParser = new DOMParser();
    }

    toElement(xmlString) {
        const parsedString = this.domParser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/html').firstElementChild;
        if (parsedString == null) {
            throw new Error(`This xml string ${xmlString} is not parsable to Node`);
        }
        return parsedString;
    }
}

const template = `
<footer>
  <slot name="prepend"></slot>
  <slot name="center"></slot>
  <slot name="append"></slot>
</footer>
`;

class AppFooter extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = template;
        this.getElementsReferences();
        this.setCopyright({
            year: '2020',
            author: 'Krzysztof Kaczyński',
            termsReferenceUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
        });
    }

    getElementsReferences() {
        this.footer = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('footer');
    }

    setCopyright({ year, author, termsReferenceUrl }) {
        const copyrightText = this.formattedCopyrights`Copyright © ${year} ${author}. Policy terms${termsReferenceUrl}`;
        this.footer.appendChild(new StringElementConverter().toElement(copyrightText));
    }

    formattedCopyrights(strings, ...values) {
        const policyTermsUrlText = `<a href="${values[values.length - 1]}">${strings[strings.length - 2]}</a>`;
        let formattedText = '<p>';
        for (let i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
            formattedText += `${strings[i]}${values[i]}`;
        }
        formattedText += `${policyTermsUrlText}</p>`;
        return formattedText;
    }
}
customElements.define('kk-app-footer', AppFooter);
```

```html
<kk-app-footer></kk-app-footer>
```