# Get element by xpath on HTML string

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have a JS variable that contains an a string that represents an HTML page. For example:

```
var response = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>This is heading 1</h1></body></html>"
```

I'd like to perform query selectors and xpath evaluations on this response to traverse through the HTML elements. Since the response is not in the DOM I can't use `document.x` actions.

One option is to write it into an invisible iframe in the DOM but this is not allowed for Chrome extensions. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: May be regex helps?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @rootkonda I was hoping for a cleaner approach, but that will be my last resort

Comment: Have you seen this already ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```js
var response = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>This is heading 1</h1></body></html>";
var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
// Example
console.log(dom.querySelector('h1').textContent);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DOMparser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to achieve that for example:

```
const response = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>This is heading 1</h1></body></html>"
const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
```

And process it as normal DOM components.