# How to extract data from AJAX's responseText?

Tags: javascript, ajax, responsetext

When I use responseText, I get all the data.  From `<HTML>` to `</HTML>`.  How to I extract specific parts of it?  For example, I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Tester</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a name="Name"></a>Name</td>
                <td>John</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a name="Email"></a>Email</td>
                <td>john@aol.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a name="Address"></a>Address</td>
                <td>123 Elm Street</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a name="City"></a>City</td>
                <td>Los Angeles</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a name="State"></a>State</td>
                <td>CA</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

And Then I need to just extract like the city part **Los Angeles**.  How would I go about doing this?  I can't do responseText.getElementByTagName, or anything like that.

Here's the AJAX call:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var pageContents = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerText = pageContents;

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","content.html",false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: perhaps you should post your ajax call as well. Not many people on this site like guessing what you're doing with your js.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question... but why can't you?  You can initiate a variable in your calling page that is global scope, set the value with the ajax page, and then make your ajax page execute whatever you script you want from the calling page.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888875/how-to-parse-html-from-javascript-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure JavaScript solution, try (untested):

```
var city = responseXML.getElementsByName('City').parentNode.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].getAttribute('textContent');
```

That said, a JavaScript library, like jQuery, to do the heavy lifting sure makes your code a lot easier to read (as well as cross-browser friendly).

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` will get `<City>` elements, not elements with the name `City`.  You want `getElementsByName`.

Comment: Hmm, see every time I try adding getElementsByName or ID to the xmlhttp.responseText I get Object doesn't support this property in IE and FF doesn't show anything.

Comment: Use `responseXML`, NOT `responseText`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery names this (sort of) easy:

`alert($('table').find('tr').eq(3).find('td').eq(1).html())`  ---> Los Angeles