# troubles trying to parse an html string with DOMParser

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, domparser

here's come the snippet :

```
html  = "<!doctype html>";
html += "<html>";
html += "<head><title>test</title></head>";
html += "<body><p>test</p></body>";
html += "</html>";

parser = new DOMParser();

dom = parser.parseFromString (html, "text/html");
```

here's come the error when trying to execute these lines :

**Error: Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsIDOMParser.parseFromString]**

I try to figure out what's going on but the code seems to be right and I searched on the web, i come here with no clues.

have you encounter this failure before ? if yes, where's the bug hiding ?

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250545/javascript-domparser-access-innerhtml-and-other-properties and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888875/how-to-parse-html-from-javascript-in-firefox

Comment: @arunes I'm using `text/html` that is why I don't get the error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use DomParser function described at [JavaScript DOMParser access innerHTML and other properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250545/javascript-domparser-access-innerhtml-and-other-properties)

I created fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/CSAnZ/

```
/* 
 * DOMParser HTML extension 
 * 2012-02-02 
 * 
 * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com 
 * Public domain. 
 * NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. 
 */  

/*! @source https://gist.github.com/1129031 */  
/*global document, DOMParser*/  

(function(DOMParser) {  
    "use strict";  
    var DOMParser_proto = DOMParser.prototype  
      , real_parseFromString = DOMParser_proto.parseFromString;

    // Firefox/Opera/IE throw errors on unsupported types  
    try {  
        // WebKit returns null on unsupported types  
        if ((new DOMParser).parseFromString("", "text/html")) {  
            // text/html parsing is natively supported  
            return;  
        }  
    } catch (ex) {}  

    DOMParser_proto.parseFromString = function(markup, type) {  
        if (/^\s*text\/html\s*(?:;|$)/i.test(type)) {  
            var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("")
              , doc_elt = doc.documentElement
              , first_elt;

            doc_elt.innerHTML = markup;
            first_elt = doc_elt.firstElementChild;

            if (doc_elt.childElementCount === 1
                && first_elt.localName.toLowerCase() === "html") {  
                doc.replaceChild(first_elt, doc_elt);  
            }  

            return doc;  
        } else {  
            return real_parseFromString.apply(this, arguments);  
        }  
    };  
}(DOMParser));
```

Comment: awesome man :) I saw this function digging into researches but I really was far from thinking it'd do the trick . thanks !