# How do I parse names out of HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript variable, for example:

```
var s = "<result>Success</result><name>George</name>";
```

How can I get with javascript regex the result 'Success' and name 'George'?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? The slash? You can escape it with `\/`, or simply match any character instead with `.`.

Comment: @KilianFoth can u show me a real example? I'm not not practical with regex :/

Comment: Is that example typical of your string, or are you actually talking about more complex data structures?

Comment: @amnotiam yes, that's is my string or better: "[result]Success[/result][name]George[/name]" i need get 'Success' and 'George'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is

```
var result = s.replace(/.*<result>([^<]*)<\/result>.*/, "$1");
var name = s.replace(/.*<name>([^<]*)<\/name>.*/, "$1");
```

However, as a general rule of thumb - don't ever use regex to parse HTML. The reason is that the browser already has XML parsers built-in, so why use ugly regex to do something the browser already does?

Parsing XML:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

Parsing HTML using the DOM: [How to parse HTML from JavaScript in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888875/how-to-parse-html-from-javascript-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT use regex with XML. Use xml parser http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: it was an example, the same string can be: var s = "[result]Success[/result][name]George[/name]"; how can I do?

Comment: If that's true, you need to work out your consistency issues... and try and keep a standard.

Comment: This is an excellent example of the typical Stack overflow answer that doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @kelloti Ok then, you should answer the question for [result]Success[/result][name]George[/name] too, cause <result>Success</result><name>George</name> was an "example"

Comment: If you noticed, his example wouldn't actually work in an XML parser because there is no parent tag. Hence why I gave him his regex answer. But I still agree, try using an XML parser when possible, so I pointed him toward that also.

Comment: It could be wrapped in a parent tag :)