# Can someone help me to find the regular expression for this using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to retrieve `71drwec4` , `51drdsf3` from the below expression 
or any other characters other than `71drwec3` between `"a_secret">` and `</div>` or something similar to that:

```
<div class="fs" id="a_secret">71drwec4</div>

<div class="fs" id="a_secre">51drdsf3</div>

<div class="fs" id="a_secr">54451drwec3</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: you need a regular formula if you want to regex it, in other words, you need to know exactly what the expression should check for each time

Comment: @colin : i am really week at regular expression...i tried this 
 
patt1 = /a_secret\/(\d+)"/;

Comment: Just as a side note, you shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID on a page

Comment: Can you simply find all `div`'s with class="fs", loop over them and get the text?

Comment: @Colin i am really noob to that :( :(

Comment: are you trying to loop through in the DOM with javascript, or is this text you're trying to evaluate with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
var pattern = /<div class="fs" id=".*?">(.*?)<\/div>/gm;
var src = '<div class="fs" id="a_secret">71drwec4</div> \n <div class="fs" id="a_secre">51drdsf3</div> \n <div class="fs" id="a_secr">54451drwec3</div>';
var match;
while (match = pattern.exec(src)) {
  alert(match[1]);
}
```

Change it as you need it (I don't know what your id's will look like or if they all have the same class, etc). If you are looking to match elements from inside your own page, jQuery would be way easier, as other posters have mentioned.

And... obligatory reference to other SO post: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use a regex for this? if the text to parse is say, HTML and you can use jQuery, you can use the `.text()` method here to retrieve the content from with an ID.

E.g.

```
var whatIwant = $("#a_secret").text();
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Its possible by jquert..but i need regular expression.thank you

Comment: what's the reason for regex? can you give a bit more background as to what you need to do? perhaps there is a simpler route.

Comment: Because i am retrieving another page source using http get request..i am saving that whole page source as an string.and with that string i am finding that particular value.

Comment: I still like this answer the best. Even if you are getting the page over http get request, you can parse the html in the resulting string and use jQuery (or even just regular dom manipulations). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888875/how-to-parse-html-from-javascript-in-firefox

Comment: Is there are need to save the page? or can you get away with simply parsing the HTML on the fly? reason I ask is that you can again use jQuery with methods such as .load() to target a specific area of a page you're making a request to and perform an action (in this case loading into a DOM node on your own page) based on the result

Answer (score 0):

```
// Match against your HTML, store matches in new 'matches' Array
var matches = htmlStr.replace(/<div.*?>(.+?)<\/div>/g, "$1 ").trim().split(' ');
```

...this assumes there are no spaces in the values you're trying to retrieve, you'd need to tweak it a bit if spaces are valid.  But against your provided test HTML:

```
<div class="fs" id="a_secret">71drwec4</div>
<div class="fs" id="a_secre">51drdsf3</div>
<div class="fs" id="a_secr">54451drwec3</div>
```

...this approach yields:

```
["71drwec4", "51drdsf3", "54451drwec3"]
```

Cheers

Comment: but i need to retrieve only content of id="a_secret i.e..71drwec4

Answer (score 0):

One of these might work with javascript.

overrun protected with <name>

```
str = '
<div
  (?=\s) 
  (?= (?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*? (?<=\s) id \s*=
      (?: (?>              \s* ([\'"]) \s* a_secret \s* \g{-1} )
        | (?> (?!\s*[\'"]) \s*             a_secret (?=\s|>) )   
      )
  )
  (?> \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ 
>
  ) (?<! /> )

(?<not_71drwec3>(?:(?!71drwec3).)*?) </div\s*>
';
```

unprotected with <name>

```
str = '
<div
  (?=\s) 
  (?= (?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*? (?<=\s) id \s*=
      (?:               \s* ([\'"]) \s* a_secret \s* \g{-1}
        |  (?!\s*[\'"]) \s*             a_secret (?=\s|>) 
      )
  )
  \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ 
>
  (?<! /> )      // line is worthless when unprotected

(?<not_71drwec3>(?:(?!71drwec3).)*?) </div\s*>
';
```

unprotected no <name> without \g{} notation

```
str = '
<div
  (?=\s) 
  (?= (?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*? (?<=\s) id \s*=
      (?:               \s* ([\'"]) \s* a_secret \s* \1    // Group 1
        |  (?!\s*[\'"]) \s*             a_secret (?=\s|>) 
      )
  )
  \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ 
>
  (?<! /> )      // line is worthless when unprotected

((?:(?!71drwec3).)*?) </div\s*>                           // Group 2
';
```